# How to hash the uploaded file name in db?

Tags: php, image, hash, mysqli

I have a "profile picture" system where every registered user can change their profile picture so the picture will show up. The process of uploading is to upload the image in the folder named `pictures` and then write the name of the file into database row named `"picture"`, it works and everything is fine but I need to know how to hash the uploaded picture's name so if 2 people with different pictures, but the same name of pictures will upload a file, there would be a problem...

Here is my submit form:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

I have this code for uploading the file to folder and to the database row:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],"pictures/".$user_id.$_FILES['file']['name']);
        $con = mysqli_connect("host","name","pass","db");
        $q = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE members SET picture = '".$_FILES['file']['name']."' WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'");
    }
?>
```

And here is code of showing the picture on the website:

```
<?php   
    $con = mysqli_connect("host","name","pass","db");
    $q = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)){
        if($row['picture'] == ""){
            echo " <img src='pictures/public_icon.png' width='25' height='25'>"; *//This is default pic//*
        } else {
            echo " <img width='25' height='25' src='pictures/".$row['picture']."' alt='Profile Pic'>"; *//And this is pic from db row//*
        }                                    
    }
?>
```

I would like to know how to hash this picture's name in the uploaded folder and also in the database row... Hot can I do it? I'd hash it with the "id" and "date" row from db but I don't know how..:/

Comment: You can append random string or number to resolve this issue.

Comment: @Toretto - how to do it?

Comment: You can also change uploaded file name at server side so there will be no conflics

Comment: @SumitPatil - Sorry, I don't know how to do it :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this for the upload instead:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

      /*
      * create a unique file name with the current time and ip address of 
      * user, since it is highly unlikely to have the same file uploaded 
      *form the same ip address at the same time
      */
      $unique_file_name = time(). $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']. $_FILES['file']['name']; 

         //run query only if file upload and transfer succeeded
         if( move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],"pictures/".$user_id. $unique_file_name) ){ 
            $con = mysqli_connect("host","name","pass","db");
            $q = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE members SET picture = '".$_FILES['file']['name']."' WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'");
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: The file name works fine, but how to pull out the name from db now?

Comment: Rather than `SELECT *` Use this:  `"SELECT `picture`

Comment: But now, it only renames the file in profile_pics folder.. the name of the file in database has the same name as the name in your/other's PC... why?

Comment: change this line: `$q = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE members SET picture = '".$_FILES['file']['name']."' WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'");`                                                             to this: `$q = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE members SET picture = '".$user_id. $unique_file_name."' WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'");` Let me know if it works

Answer (score -1):

You can try this one

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $filename = $user_id.$_FILES['file']['name'];
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],"pictures/".$filename);
            $con = mysqli_connect("host","name","pass","db");
            $q = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE members SET picture = '".$filename."' WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'");
    } ?>
```